# Submit 1 button between 2 button that has the same name and class using casperjs

Tags: jquery, casperjs

I have the html code as below:

```
<div class="formengine-steps">
    <input class="formengine-submit" type="submit" value="Etape précédente" name="action">
    <input class="formengine-submit" type="submit" value="Etape suivante" name="action">
</div>
```

I'm trying with Casperjs:

```
 this.thenClick('input.formengine-submit');
```

Problem: It does not work, because both of the buttons have the same class name. I don have the solution for this. Does anyone have the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always execute javascript from within the casper.evaluate function.  If jQuery is active on the site, it is available to you as well.  Since I'm not sure in your case, you can do the following with javascript:

```
casper.then(function() {
    casper.evaluate(function() {
        var iButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('formengine-submit');
        iButtons[0].click(); //change index to match correct button.
    });
});
```

This is not the most efficient solution, but will work based on the limited source info provided.  Provide more source and I can revise my solution for a better solution.